# How to get the first word of all array item IDs with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a bunch of divs ('.program-collector') with dynamically generated IDs. Theses IDs are usually more than one word, so I want to take all of their IDs and replace them with just the first word in the string, but I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this. I tried using the split() method...

```
$('.program-collector').each(function(k,ttl) {
    $(ttl).attr("id").split(" ")[0];
    alert($(ttl).attr("id"));
    }
};
```

... but this doesn't change the IDs, it only alerts the *full* ID with all words included. What should I be doing instead?

**edit**

To further clarify, I would want to see the div **#Acting Basics.program-collector** to become **#Acting.program-collector**, **#Web Design.program-collector** to become **#Web.program-collector**.

Comment: What is the splitter value? For example I generally have a number so `myDiv1`, `myDiv2`, `myDiv3`. The I'd split by `myDiv` and then the numbers would just be increments.

Comment: please post some sample IDs and the expected result

Comment: @JohnDoe put that in your OP so people can see it clearly.

Comment: @Alex Andrei, I would want **#Acting Basics.program-collector** to become **#Acting.program-collector**, **#Web Design.program-collector** to become **#Web.program-collector**, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
$('.program-collector').each(function(index,value) {
    id = $(value).attr("id");
    fixedID = id.split(" ")[0];
    $(value).attr("id",fixedID);
    // alert($(ttl).attr("id"));
    console.log(fixedID);
    }
};
```

You set an attribute with `.attr("attributeName","newValue")`
You get the attribute value with `.attr("attributeName")`